# Access a WCF service through a .asmx Url

Tags: wcf, iis, asmx

What ever it sounds like, I have faced the following situation:

- I have developed a wcf service in a WCF Service Library and hosted it on IIS (svc). (site\myservice.svc)
- The service should be used by a Flash client which is "trained" to work with a Web service. The client retrieves the service reference over a WebServiceHandler.serverURL + serviceName + ".asmx?WSDL"
- there is a library of a web services that contain a set services which were used by the flash app. the library has the following location site/webservices/library/[serviceName].aspx

**what I need to do:**

- make it possible to access my service under WebServiceHandler.serverURL + serviceName + ".asmx?WSDL" approach

**what I have:**

- the source code of the web service library that I can edit
- I can rebuild the library and deploy on the target server
- On the target server I can do any configuration
- IIS version 7.5

**Question:**

Do I really need to downgrade the WCF service to a Web service or there is more elegant way to do the same? (over a config file? over additional decoration of the wcf methods?)

if refactoring is the only way - what to do with FaultExeptions I throw in my WCF service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

managed to solve my issue over configuration file

1. Downloaded Url Rewrite Module http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite and installed
2. In the web.config that was on the root level of my site added

   ```
      <system.webServer>  
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SvcAsAsmx">
                    <match url="^Webservices/library/myservice.asmx(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="myservice/myservice.svc{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
   ```

more information and a possible troubleshooting is here: http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/url-rewrite-on-iis-8-aspx-to-svc.html